# cypress test failes with below error TypeError when using cypress-grep

Tags: cypress-grep

**Current behavior**
cypress test failes with below error
TypeError: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

(0 , support_1.registerCypressGrep) is not a function

**Cypress Version**
10.9.0

**Node version**
20

**Operating System**
Mac

Debug Logs
No response

cypress test failes with below error
TypeError: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

(0 , support_1.default) is not a function

Followed documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/grep